# Grey blank screen when animation is rendered

Tags: rendering, animation

New to blender, and this is my first animation. All I want is a 3d model t-shirt spinning. I placed the camera in view of it but still its grey and nothing shows.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Can you please add an image of the 'blank screen' result? To better illustrate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Iam also new to Blender,

but I guess that you not switch to the Cameraview, press the little CameraIcon on the right
or  0 on the numpad

http://builder.openhmd.net/blender-hmd-viewport-temp/editors/3dview/navigate/camera_view.html